# Empty Cells in TableView with Custom TableViewCell - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently learning `Swift` programatically. I am wanting to add a `tableView` to a `viewController` (for the purpose of being able to manipulate the constraints later) and customize the cells with a `TableViewCell`.

I can do this with my eyes closed when using the `storyboard`, but when I try to do it with just straight code I have empty cells.

My storyboard is comprised of one (1) empty `viewController` that has the custom class of `ViewController`

I have looked at others with similar issues but non of the solutions have worked. Would love to know what I am overlooking (probably something simple). Thanks in advance for the help!

**ViewController.swift:**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()
var items: [String] = ["Viper", "X", "Games"]

override func viewDidLoad() {

    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    tableView.registerClass(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->CGFloat
{
    return 50
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    //cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
    cell.companyName.text = "name"

    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

**TableViewCell:**

```
 import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var companyName = UILabel()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    companyName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)

    companyName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    contentView.addSubview(companyName)
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello @Michael First thing is you should only use awakeFromNib when you are using a .xib(Nib) and in your case you are using custom class without such xib so, you should use

```
 override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    companyName = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))
    contentView.addSubview(companyName)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

also you should initialise your label before using it.
this will solve your problem.

Read apple's documentation for subclassing UITableViewCell [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I got to after being pointed in the right direction by @replman. What do you mean by "initialise your label before using it." It is initialized.

Comment: You were just setting the frame of UILabel, as you have not made xib for your cell its better to do this before you add it to any view, so you don't end up with nil object. also you should implement prepareForReuse method in cell class to do cleanup before next use of the object.

Comment: I do not want a xib file, and I do not understand what you mean; the UIImageView is declared, framed, and added. I am not experience and issue with nil objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your custom cell to load from some custom xib you do sometimes like:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

And you should have `CustomTableViewCell.xib` file where you have table view cell with reuse identifier `CustomTableViewCell`

Comment: Yes, but as I said I am doing programmatically. So I have instead registered the class.

Comment: Helps me, thanks. Article about this approach: https://medium.com/@musawiralishah/creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-nib-xib-files-in-xcode-9bee5824e722

Answer (score 0):

Checkout how your cell's `companyLabel` is laid out. Does it exist or no?

In your code, I replaced `companyLabel` with default `textLabel` and it worked for me.

```
cell.textLabel!.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: That is the "default" textLabel for the cell (aligned center Y). My label "companyName" is located 0,0 so if it were to appear it would be tucked up in the top left corner.

I am trying to figure this out in order to add more items to the TableViewCell.

Comment: Idea here is - nothing wrong with your table view. If default cell text label shows up then your area of debugging is narrow down to custom cell. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think awakeFromNib is not called because you do not register a nib but a class. Try this instead:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let companyName = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // Initialization code
        companyName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20)
        companyName.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(companyName)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: What would that look like?

Comment: Something like this:
`override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    } `

Comment: @MichaelDavidGeppelt Why did you remove the answered flag from my answer?

Comment: what you said before providing the example led me to a solution and that is why I flagged it initially. But the example code you provided still produces blank cells. The solution you led me to was more like the current flagged answer. @replman

Comment: @MichaelDavidGeppelt that happens if one wants to quickly simplify code :-). Changed my answer just to reflect my initial comment.